# Copy contents of 2 form inputs to 1 form input

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms, copy

I have 3 forms.

Currently I am using;

```
$(document).on("ready", function(){
$('#hello').on('keyup', function() {
  $('#InputFirstName').val($(this).val());
  $('#InputFirstName1').val($(this).val());
});
$('#lastname1').on('keyup', function() {
  ('#InputLastName').val($(this).val());
  $('#InputLastName1').val($(this).val());
});
$('#InputEmail1').on('keyup', function() {
  $('#InputEmail').val($(this).val());
  $('#contactemail').val($(this).val());
});
```

to copy the text from input to input. On the third form, I have an input called "Full Name", How can I take the contents of the first 2 inputs (`#hello` and `#lastname1`) and send them to one input (`#fullname`) inline as first and last name?

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: can you post your HTML?

Comment: really not complicated since you already know how to set value. Create a new string from the values you want and set the input value with that string

Comment: I'm repeating myself from your last question BUT: `FYI, $(document).on("ready", handler); is really bad syntax for the jquery ready handler.`  ***From DOC:*** `There is also $(document).on( "ready", handler ), deprecated as of jQuery 1.8. This behaves similarly to the ready method but if the ready event has already fired and you try to .on( "ready" ) the bound handler will not be executed. Ready handlers bound this way are executed after any bound by the other three methods above.`

Comment: btw, `$(this).val()` is just more boring way to write: `this.value` ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the value of the third input like this:

```
function setFullName() {
   var firstName = $('#hello').val(),
       lastName = $('#lastname1').val();

    $('#fullname').val(firstName + " " + lastName);
}

$('#hello, #lastname1').on('keyup', setFullName);
```

Also. I think the change event could be better than keyup.

Comment: Perfect. @user1796823 any suggestions for a better change event?

Comment: Simply change keyup to change in the code, so setFullName method won't run after every keypress just after a change in the input fields and loose of focus.